# Share same disk with different servers

Tags: postgresql

I am not very exerienced in Posgresql and I did not find a solution to this question yet.
I have data in a database stored in a cloud space (onedrive). I can manage them by my Windows 10 installation of Postgres 12. I have also a laptop with linux (manjaro) installed and Postgresql server.
I would like to understand if I can access to the same cloud data with both servers. Consider that since I am a single user, data access is never concurrent. I use only one server per time.
I read it is possible to share the same data in:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/different-replication-solutions.html

Howverer, I cannot find a detailed procedure. Any suggestion ? Probably there is a better solution ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your question is pretty unclear; I'll try my best to straighten you out.

First, a database doesn't *access* data, it *holds* data. So your desire to have two database servers access the same data does not make a lot of sense.

There are three options that come to mind:

1. You want to hold only one copy of the data and want to access it from different points: in that case you don't need a server running on your laptop, only a database client that accesses the database in the cloud.

   This is the normal way to operate.
2. You want a database on your laptop to hold a cooy of the data from the other database, but you want to be able to modify the copy, so that the two database will diverge: use `pg_dump` to export the definitions and data from the cloud database and restore the dump locally.
3. You want the database on the laptop to be and remain a faithful copy of the cloud database: if your cloud provider allows replication connections, set up your laptop database as a streaming replication standby of the cloud database.

   The consequence is that you only have read access to the local cooy of the database.

Comment: You are right, sorry. Among the three options, option 2 is what I would like to get. In this case I have to look into pg_dump and possibly run it at the start up and at the end of any latop session. Thanks